# Can we pitch in to get HowToGeek a different logo?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, logo, howtogeek

So, now that HowToGeek is part of the *league of justice*, we often see the website discussed, often with some reference to the HowToGeek logo:

[image]

The **terrible, terrible** logo.

It's terribly composed, busy, jarring to look at. It's going for "hand-drawnsville" but ends up somewhere in the vicinity of "puketown."

It even reminds me of the *atrocious* comic series that used to play on the Daily WTF.

Maybe could we have a logo contest for them? Or just have Joel take a chunk of that filthy FogBugz lucre and loan them a graphic designer?

please?

Comment: I didn't want to be the first to say it, but yeah that is kinda ugly.

Comment: Tell us how you really feel about the logo.

Comment: Is it like looking in the mirror OP?

Comment: I actually like the logo...

Comment: @Ryan, you misspelled "awesome". It's a-w-e-s-o-m-e. Not "atrocious".

Comment: Wow, Jeff Atwood, How To Geek, and Alex all commenting. If I'd have known all you were reading I might not have been such a petulant douche. 

:)

Comment: @Bolt that's an ugly tag!

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard: Did I remove the wrong tag? Wow.

Comment: @Bolt yep, you just re-created the [meta-tag:ugly] tag! :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not a terrible idea. I mean, the logo was intended to be fun, friendly, and memorable, but we could make it boring and forgettable if you really want.

While we are on topic, can we discuss my idea for a much more accurate Meta logo?

[image]
<sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/up/sooooooomuchwhining.png))</sub>

=)

In all seriousness, my logo needs a little cleanup, and in fact I've got a high quality version of The Geek, but I haven't felt like changing it because it's memorable the way it is.

Comment: Ram-Man on his day off?

Comment: Was meant to indicate how much whining seems to go on over here =)

Comment: This isn't a bad attempt, but the face needs more palm. :)

Comment: I like it and think you should leave it.  Programmer Art FTW!

Answer (score 16):

[image: Where's the How-To Geek?]

Comment: Haha, so I am not the one one thinking of Waldo at first :D

Comment: Yeah, a lot of people say that =)

Comment: If it's any consolation, when my wife saw your logo yesterday she said, "Hey, that looks like you!"

Comment: Picture's broken.

Answer (score 14):

One of the runner-ups for the [SU Logo Contest](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/logo-contest-winner-for-superusercom/), the [entry](http://www.crowdspring.com/projects/graphic_design/logo/logo_for_superuser_com/gallery/03) from [mfourex](http://www.crowdspring.com/myspring/profile/mfourex), might fit nicely:

[Proposed Super User logo http://files.crowdspring.com/entry/1299908_image_03.800x800.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJW6JEGSKDSNWYXSQ&Expires=1421712000&Signature=KctpXOLu2OdK%2B70OewUnYzTgVHI%3D](http://files.crowdspring.com/entry/1299908_image_03.800x800.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJW6JEGSKDSNWYXSQ&Expires=1421712000&Signature=KctpXOLu2OdK%2B70OewUnYzTgVHI%3D)

Comment: Ohh.. I really really liked that one

Answer (score 5):

The website is the How-To Geek's own website and any design changes are likely to be up to him. Maybe you can convince him.

Comment: I just assumed that he couldn't afford a real logo and had to draw it himself. 

Except he doesn't have any hands. 

That's the only explanation I could come up with. Maybe we could also chip in for some prosthetic hands?

Comment: I almost reported instead of upvoting that comment because my hand was shaking due to laughter.

Comment: @Chacha: happened to me before.

Comment: While I have to agree that the logo is missing whatever mark it was setting out to achieve, its his own damn site - he's the only one that really has to like it. At this point its a brand unto itself, so any re-design would really have to be a part of a larger re-branding. (for a nominal fee I'll gladly help :D )

Answer (score 2):

How about..... Not.   Or maybe get one of your graphic design buddies to wip something up. Something fierce and epic.

Like a bear mauling a computer.

EDIT:

Or a pic of TheTXI beating a user.

Answer (score 2):

Origin of the How-To Geek Logo

http://blogs.howtogeek.com/howtogeek/where-did-the-how-to-geek-logo-come-from/

Themed Logos

http://www.howtogeek.com/wiki/List_of_How-To_Geek_Themed_Logos

Personally, I like the logo.

Comment: Both these links are broken. The first link 404s, the second goes to the howtogeek homepage.